# Read text line by line in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm writing an editor with syntax highlighting. What I want to do is getting the current line and just parse it instead of the whole document. The problem is that I'm probably doing it wrong but I don't know why.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    try {
    int inizio = Utilities.getRowStart(ta, ta.getCaretPosition());
    int fine = Utilities.getRowEnd(ta, ta.getCaretPosition());
    System.out.println("Inizio: " + inizio + " - Fine: " + fine);
    Element root = ta.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    if(inizio == fine) System.out.println("Mi trovo ad inizio riga");
    else {
        int linea = RXTextUtilities.getLineAtCaret(ta);
        System.out.println("Linea: " + linea);
        Element child = root.getElement(linea-1);
        System.out.println("Testo corrente: " + child.getDocument().getLength() );
    }
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My understaing of using `javax.swing.text.Element` was that I can get just the line I want (the child) and than work on that but `child.getDocument.getLength()` gives me the length of the whole document. What am I doing wrong?

**edit #1:**

`child.getDocument.getLength()` gives me the length form the start of the document, I would expect the current line length. See: I got my line number using `int linea = RXTextUtilities.getLineAtCaret(ta);` than I extract the line using root.getElement(linea-1) so I would expect that `child.getDocument().getLength()` would give me the length of the current line.

RXTextUtilities link: http://www.camick.com/java/source/RXTextUtilities.java

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Did you take into account that lines may be wrapped, i.e. a "line" may cover multiple "lines" in your textpane? Can you please state clearly what you actually expect from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case you get the length of the whole document, because `child.getDocument()` actually returns the document in which the child is embedded.

You can use `child.getStartOffset()` and `child.getEndOffset()` to determine start and end within the document and then cut out the text from the whole document.

```
int start = child.getStartOffset();
int end = child.getEndOffset();
int length = end - start;
String text = child.getDocument().getText(start, length);
```

Please note that text then also contains a EOL delimiter.